# Structures and Function return values

Tags: c++

I just started on STRUCTURES, played with them a little and got burnt!

This is the 1st exhibition:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

struct structure1{
  int h;
  int m;
  int s;
 } structVar;
 int func(structure1 x);

  int main(){
structure1 x;
      structVar.h=4;
      structVar.m=6;
      structVar.s=7;

      func(structVar);
     cout<<x.h<<x.m<<x.s<<endl;

        }

  int func(structure1 x){

    --x.h;
    --x.m;
    --x.s;

  };
```

Its output is:

```
1072276636-21953788778
```

But I expect:

```
356
```

So I tried this way, exhibition 2:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

struct structure1{
  int h;
  int m;
  int s;
 } structVar;

  struct returnstruct{
  int val1;
  int val2;
  int val3;
  }returnvalue;
 int func(structure1 x);

  int main(){

      structVar.h=4;
      structVar.m=6;
      structVar.s=7;

    func(structVar);
     cout<<returnvalue.val1<<returnvalue.val2<<returnvalue.val3<<endl;

        }

  int func(structure1 x){

    returnvalue.val1=--x.h;
    returnvalue.val2=--x.m;
    returnvalue.val3=--x.s;


  };
```

And got my required output:

```
356
```

Problem is I cant explain why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This confusion is mostly due to variable scoping.

Key points:

- function parameter names, such as `x`, are local to the function.  If a name conflict exists with a globally scoped variable, the local function parameter will take precedence.
- structs are passed *by value*, which means a copy is made and passed to the function as the parameter.

Case 1, you have the structure definition for a struct called `structure1`.  In this global scope you also have an instance of it, called `structVar`.  Then inside the scope of the `main` function, you have defined a *local* variable of type `structure1` called `x`.  The following lines

```
  structVar.h=4;
  structVar.m=6;
  structVar.s=7;
```

are modifying the *global* scoped variable, `structvar`.  Then you call

```
func(structVar);
```

This line modifies a copy of the *global* variable, `structVar` by passing it in as a function parameter to `func`.  `func` uses the name, `x` for its reference to a `structure1`, but remember, since structs are passed by value, this name is referring to a copy of whichever struct you pass to it between the parens - `func(structVar)`.  This parameter name, `x`, has no relationship to the other `x` defined in `main`.  It is specific or scoped to the body of the function, `func`.

You can explore this a bit, by changing the name of the function parameter to `y`, and first notice that it will not compile, complaining about x being undefined.  This means that within the body of that function, it doesn't know about the `x` you've defined in `main` because *that* `x` is local aka scoped only to `main`.  Contrast this with `structVar`, which is defined outside of any function's parameter list or body.  `structVar` can be referred to within either of the functions because its scope is global.

```
cout<<x.h<<x.m<<x.s<<endl;
```

Using this understanding of scope, this line then can be seen to operating on the `x` defined in `main` which has not had its members (h,m,s) initialized or assigned any values, thus the 'weird' output.

Now, let's look at the second block of code you posted.

Here, you've added another global scope struct, called `returnvalue`.  Now, you have two global scope variables, `structVar` and `returnvalue`.  Because of that scope, `structVar` is visible inside of `main`, where you are modifying its member values (h,m,s).

Next, you are passing that global variable to `func` as its parameter, `x`.  Remember, this is making a copy of `structVar`, which `func` calls `x`.  So, `x` has the values of `structVar`'s h, m, and s.

Inside of `func`, because of that global scope, it can see `returnValue`.  Using the copy of `structVar`, again now called `x`, you are setting the values of `returnvalue` to the (pre)decremented (--) values of the parameter `x`.  Since `x` is a copy of `structVar` and `structVar` had its members set to the numbers h=4, m=6, s=7, `returnvalue` then receives h=3, m=5, s=6.  `func` then returns back to `main`.

Now, back in `main`, since `returnvalue` is global scope, `main` can see it and print out its values using `cout`, thus the output of `356`

Comment: Wow! You kinda lost me in your first attempt to explain but totally did a full yard touchdown with the second. Enormous appreciation!

Comment: Variable scoping is one of those things that you fumble, until the aha moment.  Then all of a sudden you're 'passing' parameters like Cam Newton.  :)

Also, if you like my answer, accept it, so other folks will catch on quick too :)

Comment: Just started C++, so I am on to Variable scoping now. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure.  Keep at it!  Experimentation is key, so playing with the knowledge you're gaining, as you've been doing, will really help it all sink in and stick.

Comment: "The second line above then outputs the values of the local x which at this point is uninitialized, thus the 'weird' output." I thought --x.h; --x.m; --x.s; is initializing, or maybe x is initialized when I call the func function.
I tried initialising them like this
x.h=1; x.m=1; x.s=1; but does work

Comment: Well, at that point, I'm referring to your first block of code.  There, you just have a local structure1, called x, which doesn't have it's values set to anything.  In that code block, your function, func, has a *parameter* called x, which is not referring to the x in your main function.  The fact that the names are the same and that they don't refer to the same underlying place in memory is because of how they are 'scoped'.  I'll update my answer to try and show a little more clearly what's going on.

Comment: Oh! they are both quaterbacks but from different teams! Its Cam to Beckham not Rusell to Beckham. Understood!

Answer (score 0):

The value of `structure1 x` is passed by value. That means that the `func` function gets a copy of the argument that the caller never sees. So `func` can have no effect in this context unless it returns something.

You can either return the modified structure of pass `x` by reference, e.g., `structure1& x`. In the latter case x refers to the object that the function was called with.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

struct structure1{    
  int h;
  int m;
  int s;
 } structVar;         
 int func(structure1 x);

  int main(){
structure1 x;      


      structVar.h=4;  
      structVar.m=6;
      structVar.s=7;

      func(structVar);
```

I changed the line below

```
     cout<<structVar.h<<structVar.m<<structVar.s<<endl;

        }
```

I changed the function below too

```
  int func(structure1 x){  
    --structVar.h;
    --structVar.m;
    --structVar.s;


  };
```

Output is 356 as expected

Comment: @Erikest i think i got it now

Comment: If you modify the global struct structVar, why do you pass another struct to the function? ISTM that you didn't get the notion of arguments completely yet.